# Intel C++ compiler and Wnon-virtual-dtor flag gives (wrong?) warning

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, icc, virtual-destructor

I was trying to compile some code of mine which, in g++ (with the --Wnon-virtual-dtor Flag) compiled just fine. Also, my IDE and clang-tidy didn't warn me (I see that this might be false of course).

When I tried to compile the same code with Intel's icpc (actually this one `icpc (ICC) 19.1.2.254 20200623`) I got a warning which I was now able to track down - I'm wondering whether I'm somehow at fault or whether that warning is actually not correct in my case.

I wrote a somewhat minimal example of my class hierarchy:

```
template<typename T>
class B {
        public:
                B() = default;
                virtual ~B() = default;
};

template<typename T>
class C : public B<T> {
        public:
                C() = default;
                ~C() override = default;

                virtual int foo() { return 0; };
};

template<typename T>
class D : public C<T> {
        public:
                D() = default;
                ~D() override = default;
                int foo() override { return 1; };
};


int main() {
        return 0;
}
```

When compiling this with `icpc -Wnon-virtual-dtor foo.cpp` I get the following warning:

```
foo.cpp(15): warning #2026: Effective C++ Item 14 Make sure base classes C have virtual destructors
  };
   ^
```

One can get rid of that by explicitly stating that the destructor in C is virtual (so `virtual ~C() override = default;`).

Note, that also getting rid of the template lets the code compile without any warning.

For last - also getting rid of the foo member function will let the code compile without warning.

So yeah - my question is: is this a "bug" in icpc or did I do something wrong?

I was quite unable to find anything useful on that warning #2026 really.

Thanks in advance,
Flusslauf

Comment: You tagged this [c++14]?  The warning seems to be referring to "item 14" in some list of coding standards, i.e. something that's usually a good design idea, and AFAICT nothing to do with ISO C++14, so did you have some other reason for the C++ version tag?

Comment: ups yeah - my bad I think the keyword is worng.. override is available as a keyword starting from c++11, I wanted to express that. I think the warning actually relates in one or the other way to the [cpp core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) but I think it is not quite correct here.

A function that is override will be virtual by default - and I think instead of writing default int foo() override for some virtual function one should write int foo() override - same for destructors etc - and yeah, it does not happen without the template

Comment: What I meant was [this item](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c128-virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final) in the guidlines: a function should specify exactly one of override, final, and virtual. The Effective C++ Item actually refers to Scott Meyers book "effective modern c++" I tihnk, but the version I have does not have said item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after also posting this [question on the Intel forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/Warning-2026-when-compiling-with-icpc-and-Wnon-virtual-dtor/m-p/1279844/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufEtPRU44RjJWWjA0TUxTfDEyNzk4NDR8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M38755) - seems to be (a very much non critical) bug in the compiler - the workaround would be writing both, `virtual` **and** `override`.

This is discouraged by the item [C.128](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c128-virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final) in the cpp core guidelines (same link as in the comments) but not problematic.